# Como verificar se o usuário digitou algo quando solicitado uma entrada em C#

Tags: c#

A validação a seguir verifica se uma entrada é um número positivo.

```
if (Q[i] < 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("Digite um número positivo!");
    goto Start;
}
```

Assim como esta verificação, caso nada fosse digitado, o programa apenas voltaria para o "Start" sem apresentar um erro.

Isto é, como faço para verificar se a entrada for vazia, pois o usuário não digitou nada?

Comment: Trate com alguma variável se a entrada de dados é NULL ou não.

string text;

if (text == NULL){
   Console.WriteLine("Não foi digitado nada");
}
else{
   Console.WriteLine("Foi digitado : ", text);
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Console.Write("Informe um valor: ");
 string value = Console.ReadLine();
 if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
 {
     Console.WriteLine("O usuário não informou valor");
     goto Start;
 }
 else
 {
    Console.WriteLine("O valor é: {0}", s);
 }
```

Observe que usei o método booleano [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx), pois ela indica se uma cadeia de caracteres especificada é null, vazia ou consiste apenas em caracteres de espaço em branco. Logo se a variável não tiver nenhum caractere, consequentemente entrará no primeiro ***if***, informando que o usuário não digitou nenhum valor.

Espero ter ajudado.